# working on the list and writing the outut on csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of names and code as string, that looks like this:

```
['Daniel', '5104', 'peter', '9770']
```

How can I change it in this order, making a list of every name and number and update the first list with them, like this:

```
[['Daniel', '5104'], ['peter', '9770']]
```

Finally I'm going to write that list on the `csv` file in the following order:

```
daniel,5104
peter,9770
```

Here is my code for writing the data to the `.csv` file:

```
with open('code.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file_name:
  writer = csv.writer(output_file_name)
  writer.writerows(data)
  output_file_name.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this with a list comprehension.

```
l = ['Daniel', '5104', 'peter', '9770']
print([l[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(l), 2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this :

```
lst = ['Daniel', '5104', 'peter', '9770']
print zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])


>>> [('Daniel', '5104'), ('peter', '9770')]
```

`lst[1::2]` standing for "lst, starting at index 1, taking one element every 2"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `islice` from `itertools`. Below code should work.

```
from itertools import islice

input = ['Daniel', '5104', 'peter', '9770']

print(list(zip(islice(input,0, len(input), 2), islice(input,1, len(input), 2))))
```

Output:

```
[('Daniel', '5104'), ('peter', '9770')]
```

You can do the below, if you want list only.

```
print(list(map(list, zip(
    islice(input,0, len(input), 2),
    islice(input,1, len(input), 2)
    ))))
```

Comment: this is overkill, a simple list comprehension is much cleaner and more readable

Comment: Thank, but I need a big list, that contain every name and the code as a list in it:
[['Daniel', '5104'], ['peter', '9770']]

Comment: @aws_apprentice, this is more functional approach, kind of like LISP and clojure. Anything is fine. It is a matter of taste.

Comment: it's about code readability, there's nothing wrong with using functional programming but when the solution makes it less readable then it is usually not the way to go, especially in a language like python where readability is essential

Answer (score 0):

If you know by advance the shape of your list, you can loop through the list with a defined step so that you can get the datas in the right order. For example, if the list always look like this :

```py
['name1','number1','name2','number2',...]
```

where `name1` is to be associated with `number1`, `name2` with `number2`,..., you can use a for loop with a step of 2, so that you get all names and can easily get the number, like this :

```py
myInputList = ['name1','number1','name2','number2']
myOutputList = []
for i in range(0,len(myList),2):
    myOuputList.append([myInputList[i],myInputList[i+1])
```

It should work like this.

Hope it helps.